# Регулярка для замены скобок в определенной части строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вопрос вроде не самый сложный, но сообразить как это сделать никак не могу.
Есть например кусок кода:

```
<h3 class="category__title ng-binding">{{ "field.family.title" | trans }}</h3>
{% verbatim %}
    <p>{{ selectedProducts[currentProductIndex].type.typeName }}</p>
    <p>{{ selectedProducts[currentProductIndex].type.number }}</p>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Как заменить именно фигурные скобки внутри `{% verbatim %}...{% endverbatim %}`?

Comment: На что заменить?

Comment: {{ заменить на [[

Comment: По той ссылке, что в "дубле"  КРЫША и ПОДВАЛ заменить на ваши строки начала и окончания блока.

Comment: Большое спасибо!